# Update sites for two versions of the product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to update my product to a later version. Let's say product I am trying to update is at version 1.0.0 and there are two update sites available, one that has version 1.5.0 and another that has 2.0.0. Both update sites are in the update site manager. When I click "Check for Updates" I find only version 2.0.0, not 1.5.0. If I disable update site for 2.0.0 then 1.5.0 shows up during update check. Is there a way to control what updates make into available updates? Is there way to make it so both 1.5.0 and 2.0.0 show up so I can choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". The check for updates feature is not designed to give user a selection of versions. In Juno and earlier, it will attempt to update to the latest known version and fail if that's not possible. In Kepler, it will attempt to update to the latest version that can be installed given system constraints, so the update is more likely to succeed. In either version, the user doesn't get to pick among versions when updating.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why it was done like this? I see use-case for my question when user is at release 1.5.0 of the software and update site for the product includes url for main update, let's say at version 2.0.0. There was an update 1.5.1 and user wants to install this update, but he wouldn't be able to unless he disables main update and enters url for 1.5.1 update site.

Comment: The assumption is that there is no reason for a typical user to install an older version when a newer one is available and is installable given local constraints. Users wanting more flexibility can do what you are doing or just installing a specific version directly (Eclipse will turn an install request into an upgrade if an older version is found).